Computational efficiency of Galerkin projection in AMG
I have been using recently AMG as preconditioner for CG with several meshes for simple elliptic problems discretised with linear elements on "complicated" three dimensional geometries and I was quite puzzled by its efficiency (I tried both with Trilinos and PETSc).
Given that a coarse-level operator $A_1$ can be built out of the original matrix of the problem $A_0$ through Galerkin projection, using prolongation and restriction operators $P$ and $R$, respectively:
$$A_1 = RA_0P$$
which will be applied to vectors during the algorithm. Does anyone have some insights on how such mat-vice product is done efficiently inside the AMG recursion? It will probably not be just a mere application of three vector products I guess. Even some references about the implementation strategies related to efficient AMG methods are well appreciated!

There is a large literature on how AMG is implemented. What have you already found and read? You might want to start reading from the authors of the hypre (in PETSc) and ML/MueLu (in Trilinos) packages.
